# Hyperlink shortcut to create a post on Linkedin?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'd like to have a hyperlink, which, when clicked, will take the user to LinkedIn, open up the "Start a Post" pop-up, and ideally (optional) also tag a company (@companyname).

As an example, I know I can do the equivalent on Google to instantly bring up the "write a review" interface, with a URL like https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=xxx

Is this possible with LinkedIn, and if so, what URL should I use?